# Using XBOX360 pad (for Windows) in Windows Phone 7 Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna-4.0, xbox360

I want to use XBOX360 controller to emulate user input in my Windows Phone 7 game ( created in XNA 4). But I am unable to read pad state - property `GamePadState.IsConnected`is set to false, although my pad is connected and efficient. I thought that pad's input may be disabled by default, just like keyboard ones ( page up / break activate it), but I was unable to find right button / button combination.

My question: Is it possible to handle XBOX 360 pad input in windows phone 7 game ( XNA 4) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the Xbox 360 gamepad in the context of a Windows Phone 7 applications - for obvious reasons (you cannot connect it to a physical device later on).

Answer (score 1):

The GamePad class can be used to detect that the Back button is pressed on the phone:

```
if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
  // do something      
}
```

I don't believe that will detect the back button on the actual gamepad, just the button on the phone.